# AWS Cross Region Replication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, replication

I want to move assets from a bucket in one region to another bucket in anthoer region and was pointed towards using Cross Region Replication however I've been told that CRR wont work from a replicated bucket to another replicated bucket. Unfortunatly we can't change our source bucket to be non replicated due to the way we have streaming assets delivered.
Does anyone know of a work around for this?

Comment: *"I've been told that CRR wont work from a replicated bucket to another replicated bucket."*  That isn't entirely true.  In a cascade of replicating buckets A > B > C, objects created in B replicate to C, and objects created in A replicate to B, but objects created in A are not subsequently replicated from B to C.  That is the sense in which it "won't work."

Comment: @Neil is this a one-off requirement, or does it need to be done on a continuing basis?

Comment: This is a continuing job - @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 0):

You can create an **Amazon S3 Event** on Bucket B that is triggered when a new object is created.

The Lambda function could call `CopyObject()` to copy the new object to Bucket C.